# SonarQube Test coverage issue when using sonar-maven-plugin with jacoco

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco-maven-plugin

We have a multi module maven project where the sonar-maven-plugin and jacoco maven-plugin are defined in the parent pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/generated/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
```

Now we have a submodule common, containing again other submodules:

[image: project structure]

In the submodule common, the maven structure is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <parent>
       <groupId>be.groupname</groupId>
       <artifactId>artifactname</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>be.groupname</groupId>
   <artifactId>common-master</artifactId>
   <name>Common - Master</name>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>
   <modules>
       <module>bindings</module>
       <module>core</module>
       <module>tools</module>
   </modules>
</project>
```

The submodule core has the following maven structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>be.groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-master</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>common-core</artifactId>
    <name>Common - Core</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

Now my question, in my SonarQube report, I see the uncovered lines:

[image: test coverage]

The common master project contains all the uncovered lines from the submodules (common-core,...). I would expect that only the common core module would contain those lines.

In the filesystem, I see a jacoco.exec is generated under the common/target folder.
In the subdirectory common, I don't see this file being created but instead I see a file common/core/target/sonar/jacoco-overall.exec

Comment: As I know, Sonar represents the coverage as a tree so you will find the sum of the module coverage on the parent and each module will have the sum of covergae of its children and so on

Comment: @jMounir You are totally right. I thought the uncovered lines from the parent and each submodule where added to arrive at the total count. When I did the calculation, I noticed you are right and sonar indeed shows the coverage on the parent as the sum of the coverage of its children. Thanks